# Filter and de dupe Javascript Objects based on it's property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, underscore.js

Based on the "Platform" and "Title", I need to de dupe the following object and get the earliest "DateFirstSeen" and latest "DateLastSeen".

Input Object:

```
[
 {
    "Platform": "Disney",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "15",
      "Month": "06",
      "Year": "2019"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "08",
      "Month": "02",
      "Year": "2021"
    },
    "Title": "Jojo Rabbit"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Netflix",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2014"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "11",
      "Year": "2020"
    },
    "Title": "Stranger Things"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Netflix",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "20",
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2014"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "02",
      "Month": "03",
      "Year": "2020"
    },
    "Title": "Stranger Things"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Netflix",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2014"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "10",
      "Year": "2017"
    },
    "Title": "Stranger Things"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Netflix",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2012"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "05",
      "Month": "01",
      "Year": "2017"
    },
    "Title": "Stranger Things"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Hulu",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "05",
      "Year": "2010"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2016"
    },
    "Title": "Watchmen"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Netflix",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "03",
      "Month": "04",
      "Year": "2015"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "03",
      "Month": "04",
      "Year": "2015"
    },
    "Title": "Stranger Things"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "20",
      "Month": "07",
      "Year": "2005"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2012"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Hulu",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "01",
      "Year": "2012"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "01",
      "Year": "2012"
    },
    "Title": "Watchmen"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "09",
      "Year": "2003"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "02",
      "Year": "2009"
    },
    "Title": "Snoopy Show"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "01",
      "Month": "11",
      "Year": "2008"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "03",
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2008"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "09",
      "Year": "2008"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "09",
      "Year": "2008"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "06",
      "Year": "1999"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "31",
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2006"
    },
    "Title": "Snoopy Show"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "12",
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2006"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "12",
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2006"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "18",
      "Month": "06",
      "Year": "2006"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "18",
      "Month": "06",
      "Year": "2006"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2005"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "08",
      "Year": "2005"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "20",
      "Month": "07",
      "Year": "2005"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "20",
      "Month": "07",
      "Year": "2005"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  }
]
```

The desired output is:

```
 [
  {
    "Platform": "Disney",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "15",
      "Month": "06",
      "Year": "2019"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Day": "08",
      "Month": "02",
      "Year": "2021"
    },
    "Title": "Jojo Rabbit"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Netflix",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2012"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "11",
      "Year": "2020"
    },
    "Title": "Stranger Things"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "Hulu",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "05",
      "Year": "2010"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2016"
    },
    "Title": "Watchmen"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Day": "20",
      "Month": "07",
      "Year": "2005"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "12",
      "Year": "2012"
    },
    "Title": "See"
  },
  {
    "Platform": "AppleTV",
    "DateFirstSeen": {
      "Month": "06",
      "Year": "1999"
    },
    "DateLastSeen": {
      "Month": "02",
      "Year": "2009"
    },
    "Title": "Snoopy Show"
  }
]
```

I had tried using underscore to get all the unique objects `_.uniq` but that only gives me the unique values of the platform and the title but misses out on DateFirstSeen and DateLastSeen.

I want to make sure those fields aren't lost in the filtering process.

Comment: In js you can use Array.filter to filter, then Array.sort according to dates, then Array.reduce to get the min or max (or take the first value of the sorted array)

Comment: It would help if you showed your (non-working) code based on `_.uniq`; show your research effort so that answers can build on that.

Answer (score 1):

With the following helper function,

```
function dayNumber(dateObj) {
    var day = _.get(dateObj, 'Day', 1),
        month = _.get(dateObj, 'Month'),
        year = _.get(dateObj, 'Year');
    return year * 372 + month * 31 + +day;
}
```

The following expression will compute the desired output:

```
_.chain(data).groupBy('Platform').map(function(platformData, platform) {
    return _.chain(platformData).groupBy('Title').map(function(titleData, title) {
        var titleChain = _.chain(titleData),
            firstSeen = titleChain.map('DateFirstSeen').min(dayNumber),
            lastSeen = titleChain.map('DateLastSeen').max(dayNumber);
        return {
            Platform: platform,
            Title: title,
            DateFirstSeen: firstSeen.value(),
            DateLastSeen: lastSeen.value()
        };
    }).value();
}).flatten().value();
```

Let's take this apart.

```
function dayNumber(dateObj) {
```

We start by writing a function that takes a date object such as `{ "Day": "20", "Month": "07", "Year": "2005" }` and returns a single number. We need this in order to be able to apply [`_.min`](https://underscorejs.org/#min) and [`_.max`](https://underscorejs.org/#max), which can compute the minimum and the maximum of a collection, respectively.

```
    var day = _.get(dateObj, 'Day', 1),
```

Inside the `dayNumber` function, we proceed by taking the parts out of the `dateObj`. The [`_.get`](https://underscorejs.org/#get) function lets us specify a fallback value (`1` in this case), which comes in handy because not all date objects have a `Day` property.

```
        month = _.get(dateObj, 'Month'),
        year = _.get(dateObj, 'Year');
    return year * 372 + month * 31 + +day;
}
```

With these parts, we calculate an approximation of the number of days since the start of the Western calendar. The value is obviously inaccurate, because we are pretending that every month has 31 days, but it will still get the relative order of the dates right. Note that we use the notation `+day` in order to coerce the `Day` property to number. The year and the month are coerced by the fact that we multiply them with a number.

With the `dayNumber` function in place, we can move on to the big expression.

```
_.chain(data)
```

We use [`_.chain`](https://underscorejs.org/#chain) so that we can apply several Underscore functions in succession, each operating on the result of the previous Underscore function. We will see this a few more times in the remainder of the expression.

```
.groupBy('Platform')
```

Still on this first line, we first group the data by the `Platform` property. This creates an object, where each key is a platform name and the corresponding value is the subset of the data from that platform:

```
{
    Disney: [...],
    Netflix: [...],
    Hulu: [...],
    AppleTV: [...]
}
```

This intermediate result is immediately chained into the next Underscore function:

```
.map(function(platformData, platform) {
```

For each pair of platform name and its corresponding data, we will be computing some kind of result and then return all results in an array (see [`_.map`](https://underscorejs.org/#map)). On the next line, we find ourselves inside the function that will compute one such result.

```
    return _.chain(platformData).groupBy('Title').map(function(titleData, title) {
```

This line looks strikingly similar to the previous line. Instead of all data, we only group the data for a single platform, and we group them by title. There is a `return` statement in front, which means that the end result of this chain will also be the computed result for the entire platform.

```
        var titleChain = _.chain(titleData),
```

We make yet another chain for the subset of data of a single title. We give this chain a name (`titleChain`), because we will be using it twice.

```
            firstSeen = titleChain.map('DateFirstSeen').min(dayNumber),
            lastSeen = titleChain.map('DateLastSeen').max(dayNumber);
```

We finally get to business! First, we extract all `DateFirstSeen` properties out of the `titleData`, and then we take the earliest using `_.min` and our `dayNumber` helper function. Similarly, we find the latest `DateLastSeen` using `_.max`.

```
        return {
            Platform: platform,
            Title: title,
            DateFirstSeen: firstSeen.value(),
            DateLastSeen: lastSeen.value()
        };
```

We have all information complete about this single title, so we recombine the data into a new object. We use [`_().value`](https://underscorejs.org/#value) to take the results out of our chains.

```
    }).value();
```

We close the function that computes the result for a single title as well as the call to `_.map` to which we passed this function. We end the chain that computes the result for a whole platform as well and take its `.value()`. This is an array of title objects.

```
}).flatten().value();
```

Finally, we close the whole expression. We insert a call to [`_.flatten`](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten), because otherwise we'll have an array of arrays instead of just a single flat array.

**Note:** if we had a guarantee that every title appears on only one platform, we could skip grouping by platform and we wouldn't need to `flatten` at the end. The code is simpler in this case and also a little bit faster:

```
_.chain(data).groupBy('Title').map(function(titleData, title) {
    var titleChain = _.chain(titleData),
        firstSeen = titleChain.map('DateFirstSeen').min(formatAsDate),
        lastSeen = titleChain.map('DateLastSeen').max(formatAsDate);
    return {
        Platform: _.first(titleData).Platform,
        Title: title,
        DateFirstSeen: firstSeen.value(),
        DateLastSeen: lastSeen.value()
    };
}).value();
```

Since we are no longer grouping by platform, we no longer have a `platform` argument to close over, so we get the platform name using [`_.first`](https://underscorejs.org/#first) instead. Generally, you can't assume that an array has a first element (since an array may be empty), but here it is safe because `groupBy` never produces empty groups.

This simpler expression happens to work for your example data, but in general it is probably not safe to assume that every title is unique to a single platform. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    const data =  [
     {
        "Platform": "Disney",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "15",
          "Month": "06",
          "Year": "2019"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "08",
          "Month": "02",
          "Year": "2021"
        },
        "Title": "Jojo Rabbit"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Netflix",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2014"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "11",
          "Year": "2020"
        },
        "Title": "Stranger Things"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Netflix",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "20",
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2014"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "02",
          "Month": "03",
          "Year": "2020"
        },
        "Title": "Stranger Things"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Netflix",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2014"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "10",
          "Year": "2017"
        },
        "Title": "Stranger Things"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Netflix",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "12",
          "Year": "2012"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "05",
          "Month": "01",
          "Year": "2017"
        },
        "Title": "Stranger Things"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Hulu",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "05",
          "Year": "2010"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "12",
          "Year": "2016"
        },
        "Title": "Watchmen"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Netflix",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "03",
          "Month": "04",
          "Year": "2015"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "03",
          "Month": "04",
          "Year": "2015"
        },
        "Title": "Stranger Things"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "20",
          "Month": "07",
          "Year": "2005"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "12",
          "Year": "2012"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "Hulu",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "01",
          "Year": "2012"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "01",
          "Year": "2012"
        },
        "Title": "Watchmen"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "09",
          "Year": "2003"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "02",
          "Year": "2009"
        },
        "Title": "Snoopy Show"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "01",
          "Month": "11",
          "Year": "2008"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "03",
          "Month": "12",
          "Year": "2008"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "09",
          "Year": "2008"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "09",
          "Year": "2008"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "06",
          "Year": "1999"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "31",
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2006"
        },
        "Title": "Snoopy Show"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "12",
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2006"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "12",
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2006"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "18",
          "Month": "06",
          "Year": "2006"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "18",
          "Month": "06",
          "Year": "2006"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2005"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Month": "08",
          "Year": "2005"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      },
      {
        "Platform": "AppleTV",
        "DateFirstSeen": {
          "Day": "20",
          "Month": "07",
          "Year": "2005"
        },
        "DateLastSeen": {
          "Day": "20",
          "Month": "07",
          "Year": "2005"
        },
        "Title": "See"
      }
    ];
    const result = data.reduce((a,it)=>{
     const index = a.map(i=>i.Title).indexOf(it.Title);
     if(index===-1){
       a.push(it);
     }else{
       if(a[index].DateLastSeen.Year < it.DateLastSeen.Year || a[index].DateLastSeen.Month < it.DateLastSeen.Month){
       a[index].DateLastSeen = it.DateLastSeen;
        }
     }
    return a;
    },[])
    console.log(result);
```